# Does Dart have sprintf, or does it only have interpolation?

Tags: string, format, printf, dart

I would like to emulate C's `sprintf("%02d", x);` in Dart, but I can't find string formatting, only string interpolation.

Answer (score 12):

String interpolation covers most of your needs. If you want to format numbers directly, there is also [`num.toStringAsPrecision()`](http://api.dartlang.org/dart_core/num.html#toStringAsPrecision).

Comment: That's helpful, but I need a way to combine precision and radix, e.g. `sprintf("%02x", 0x0f)`.

Comment: not sure I agree the string interpolation covers everything. printf/format makes constructs such as **sprintf("%08d", number)** (format number with up to 8 leading zeroes) and **sprintf("%.3f", number)** (Round number to 3 digits after decimal point) very easy. Most languages I have used that has string interpolation also have a printf functionality (Perl, Ruby,...).

Answer (score 8):

I took a different approach to this issue: by padding the string directly, I don't have to use any libraries (mainly because the intl library seems to be discontinued):

```
x.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
```

Would be the equivalent of sprintf("%02d", x);

Comment: Beautiful. This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 6):

A **String.format** method does not currently exists but there is a [bug/feature request](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/1694) for adding it.

Comment: This issue doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, it looks like it does exist, but manages to trigger a 500 response. [Searching the issue tracker for 'sprintf' will list it as an issue.](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list?q=sprintf) From the listing page, the issue can be stared, if you want to follow it.

Answer (score 6):

The intl library provides several helpers to format values.
See the API documentation at http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/intl.html

Here is an example on how to convert a number into a two character string:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
    var twoDigits = new NumberFormat("00", "en_US");
    print(twoDigits.format(new Duration(seconds: 8)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation of String.format for Dart. It is not perfect but works good enough for me:

```dart
static String format(String fmt,List<Object> params) {
  int matchIndex = 0;
  String replace(Match m) {
    if (matchIndex<params.length) {
      switch (m[4]) {
        case "f":
          num val = params[matchIndex++];
          String str;
          if (m[3]!=null && m[3].startsWith(".")) {
            str = val.toStringAsFixed(int.parse(m[3].substring(1)));
          } else {
            str = val.toString();
          }
          if (m[2]!=null && m[2].startsWith("0")) {
             if (val<0) {
               str = "-"+str.substring(1).padLeft(int.parse(m[2]),"0");
             } else {
               str = str.padLeft(int.parse(m[2]),"0");
             }
          }
          return str;
        case "d":
        case "x":
        case "X":
          int val = params[matchIndex++];
          String str = (m[4]=="d")?val.toString():val.toRadixString(16); 
          if (m[2]!=null && m[2].startsWith("0")) {
            if (val<0) {
              str = "-"+str.substring(1).padLeft(int.parse(m[2]),"0");
            } else {
              str = str.padLeft(int.parse(m[2]),"0");
            }
          }
          return (m[4]=="X")?str.toUpperCase():str.toLowerCase();
        case "s":
          return params[matchIndex++].toString(); 
      }
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Missing parameter for string format");
    }
    throw new Exception("Invalid format string: "+m[0].toString());
  }
```

Test output follows:

```dart
  format("%d", [1]) // 1
  format("%02d", [2]) // 02
  format("%.2f", [3.5]) // 3.50
  format("%08.2f", [4]) // 00004.00
  format("%s %s", ["A","B"]) // A B
  format("%x", [63]) // 3f
  format("%04x", [63]) // 003f
  format("%X", [63]) //3F
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Dart has a sprintf package:
https://pub.dev/packages/sprintf.
It is modeled after C's sprintf.

Answer (score 0):

See a [format package](https://pub.dev/packages/format). It is similar to format() from Python. It is a new package. Needs testing.